# Source, but run a command after every command

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have a list of shell commands in a file, always 1 command per line. I run these with `source cmds.sh` and all is good.

The commands generally do some tasks and print output. However, it is a bit difficult to tell where one command's output ends and another's begins. If I could run something like `echo "-----"` after every sourced command it would be much easier.

How can I do this in a concise way?

Comment: You can put `set -v` in the front of the script, which makes bash print out each command before it is run.

Comment: If you don't mind starting another shell, you could pipe through bash - `sed 's/$/;echo ------/' cmd.sh | bash`

Comment: a `DEBUG` trap is the obvious approach.

Comment: Or use `PS4` -- that'll not only be a separator but you can put the line number the code comes from

Comment: that is: `PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -x` at the top of your script

Comment: And remember to `set +x` at the end of your script because `source`d scripts will propagate the `DEBUG` option to your interactive shell.

Comment: Why not just edit the file?

Answer (score 0):

Using a recent version of bash?

Put `trap 'echo -----' debug` at the top of your sourced file, and maybe `trap -- debug` at the bottom.